# Raspberry Pi 2 does not recognize USB memories

Tags: usb, pi-2, usb-hub

I have raspberry Pi 2 connected with usb-HUB and I have some problems with the memory sticks.

```
I have:
8 gb usb memory in ext4 format, 
8 gb usb memory in fat format, 
1 tb external hdd in NTFS format.
```

When I connect then for the first time there is not problem, but when I restart the rpi, both of 8gb sticks are not recognized. With the external hdd there is not problem at all.

I check with:

```
lsblk
```

and the result is:

```
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
    `-sda1        8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/Seagate Expansion Drive
    mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk
    |-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 814.3M  0 part /media/RECOVERY
    |-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0     1K  0 part
    |-mmcblk0p3 179:3    0    32M  0 part /media/SETTINGS
....
```

There is not sign of any of the usb sticks.

Does someone know how to fix it?

---

Edit to add dmesg: (now is a new 1.9Gb usb stick connected directly to rpi, are still two 8gb memory sticks connected but not recognized)

```
osmc@osmc:~$ dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.10-1-osmc (root@vero) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 6 15:34:17 UTC 2015
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x2e800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 192512
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 809abd40, node_mem_map ae213000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1504 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 192512 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (8640->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 10 pages/cpu @ae1e1000 s12096 r8192 d20672 u40960
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s12096 r8192 d20672 u40960 alloc=10*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 191008
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1776 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=952 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa01041 bcm2709.serial=0x783d95bd smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:3D:95:BD bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.disk_led_gpio=47 bcm2709.disk_led_active_low=0 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 osmcdev=rbp2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait quiet
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 744108K/770048K available (7245K kernel code, 401K rwdata, 1864K rodata, 392K init, 763K bss, 25940K reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xffe00000   (2048 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xaf800000 - 0xff000000   (1272 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xaf000000   ( 752 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x808ed900   (9111 kB)
      .init : 0x808ee000 - 0x80950000   ( 392 kB)
      .data : 0x80950000 - 0x809b461c   ( 402 kB)
       .bss : 0x809b461c - 0x80a734d4   ( 764 kB)
    [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
    [    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
    [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:608
    [    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (virt).
    [    0.000016] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 3579139424256ns
    [    0.000039] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
    [    0.000332] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
    [    0.000538] console [tty0] enabled
    [    0.000564] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
    [    0.000591] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
    [    0.000985] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.001009] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
    [    0.002234] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
    [    0.002290] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
    [    0.002318] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
    [    0.002342] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
    [    0.002377] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
    [    0.002456] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
    [    0.002536] ftrace: allocating 18147 entries in 54 pages
    [    0.046114] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
    [    0.046153] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 15, mpidr 80000f00
    [    0.046171] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
    [    0.046312] Setting up static identity map for 0x6adf68 - 0x6adfc0
    [    0.106073] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 18
    [    0.106374] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
    [    0.106382] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
    [    0.106435] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
    [    0.106444] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 15, mpidr 80000f01
    [    0.126047] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 18
    [    0.126304] CPU2: Booted secondary processor
    [    0.126310] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
    [    0.126343] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
    [    0.126351] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 15, mpidr 80000f02
    [    0.146075] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 18
    [    0.146316] CPU3: Booted secondary processor
    [    0.146323] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
    [    0.146355] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
    [    0.146363] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 15, mpidr 80000f03
    [    0.146455] Brought up 4 CPUs
    [    0.146489] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
    [    0.146500] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
    [    0.147506] devtmpfs: initialized
    [    0.171418] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
    [    0.173447] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
    [    0.176392] NET: Registered protocol family 16
    [    0.181738] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
    [    0.205876] cpuidle: using governor ladder
    [    0.235898] cpuidle: using governor menu
    [    0.236037] bcm2709.uart_clock = 3000000
    [    0.238824] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
    [    0.238845] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
    [    0.238880] mailbox: Broadcom VideoCore Mailbox driver
    [    0.238992] bcm2708_vcio: mailbox at f300b880
    [    0.239335] bcm_power: Broadcom power driver
    [    0.239352] bcm_power_open() -> 0
    [    0.239363] bcm_power_request(0, 8)
    [    0.740030] bcm_mailbox_read -> 00000080, 0
    [    0.740043] bcm_power_request -> 0
    [    0.740162] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
    [    0.740295] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
    [    0.808432] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.808678] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.808794] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.808943] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.810593] Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
    [    0.838939] FS-Cache: Loaded
    [    0.839277] CacheFiles: Loaded
    [    0.851053] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.852348] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
    [    0.852494] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
    [    0.852688] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
    [    0.852800] TCP: reno registered
    [    0.852823] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.852887] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
    [    0.853370] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    0.853793] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
    [    0.853809] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
    [    0.853820] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
    [    0.853831] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
    [    0.854284] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
    [    0.854504] bcm2708_dma: DMA manager at f3007000
    [    0.854682] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
    [    0.856288] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
    [    0.856502] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
    [    0.856564] audit: type=2000 audit(0.829:1): initialized
    [    0.872376] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
    [    0.872751] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.875661] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
    [    0.876675] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
    [    0.876746] Key type id_resolver registered
    [    0.876759] Key type id_legacy registered
    [    0.877771] msgmni has been set to 1469
    [    0.879735] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
    [    0.879938] io scheduler noop registered
    [    0.880249] io scheduler bfq registered (default)
    [    0.880261] BFQ I/O-scheduler version: v7r7
    [    0.882744] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory eec00000
    [    0.882785] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f3007000
    [    0.910563] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 222x59
    [    0.928876] bcm2708-dmaengine bcm2708-dmaengine: Load BCM2835 DMA engine driver
    [    0.929181] uart-pl011 dev:f1: no DMA platform data
    [    0.929670] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
    [    0.929684] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
    [    0.929696] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
    [    0.929707] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
    [    0.941305] brd: module loaded
    [    0.947112] loop: module loaded
    [    0.947423] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xae800000, is_master = 0
    [    0.948252] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
    [    0.949196] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
    [    0.949273] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
    [    1.149633] Core Release: 2.80a
    [    1.149655] Setting default values for core params
    [    1.149683] Finished setting default values for core params
    [    1.350087] Using Buffer DMA mode
    [    1.350103] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
    [    1.350114] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
    [    1.350125] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
    [    1.350143] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
    [    1.350531] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xaec14000 dma = 0xeec14000 len=9024
    [    1.350571] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
    Non-periodic Split Transactions
    Periodic Split Transactions
    High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
    [    1.350630] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
    [    1.350704] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:412: FIQ on core 1 at 0x804f836c
    [    1.350724] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ ASM at 0x804f86dc length 36
    [    1.350743] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:438: MPHI regs_base at 0xaf80a000
    [    1.350772] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
    [    1.350824] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [    1.350872] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
    [    1.350926] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
    [    1.350936] Init: Power Port (0)
    [    1.351251] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    1.351273] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.351289] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
    [    1.351305] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.18.10-1-osmc dwc_otg_hcd
    [    1.351320] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
    [    1.352334] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [    1.352404] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
    [    1.352936] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
    [    1.352950] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
    [    1.352961] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
    [    1.353003] Module dwc_common_port init
    [    1.353399] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    [    1.353675] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
    [    1.354593] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=900000
    [    1.354903] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
    [    1.354916] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
    [    1.355098] DMA channels allocated for the MMC driver
    [    1.390626] Load BCM2835 MMC driver
    [    1.390933] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
    [    1.396805] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
    [    1.399157] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
    [    1.399482] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [    1.399495] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [    1.400948] TCP: cubic registered
    [    1.400971] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
    [    1.401013] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    1.403270] Key type dns_resolver registered
    [    1.403450] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
    [    1.407602] registered taskstats version 1
    [    1.410797] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
    [    1.410818] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
    [    1.411648] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
    [    1.412743] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p6...
    [    1.439379] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
    [    1.441829] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
    [    1.442443] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD8GB 7.42 GiB
    [    1.448156]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 > p3
    [    1.537046] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    1.537119] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:6.
    [    1.547824] devtmpfs: mounted
    [    1.548513] Freeing unused kernel memory: 392K (808ee000 - 80950000)
    [    1.550807] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
    [    1.730753] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
    [    1.730952] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
    [    1.931041] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
    [    1.931073] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    1.932186] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
    [    1.932322] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
    [    2.210890] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
    [    2.311101] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
    [    2.311131] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.314245] smsc95xx v1.0.4
    [    2.374666] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:3d:95:bd
    [    2.450829] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
    [    2.553461] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=3100
    [    2.553492] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [    2.553510] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB DISK 2.0
    [    2.553525] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer:
    [    2.553540] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 07981BF06097B2EE
    [    2.554643] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [    2.555834] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
    [    2.650895] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
    [    2.752371] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
    [    2.752403] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.752420] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB2.0 Hub
    [    2.753741] hub 1-1.5:1.0: USB hub found
    [    2.754126] hub 1-1.5:1.0: 4 ports detected
    [    3.031080] usb 1-1.5.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
    [    3.232589] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=1702
    [    3.232620] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    3.232636] usb 1-1.5.2: Product: USB Keyboard
    [    3.232651] usb 1-1.5.2: Manufacturer:
    [    3.280707] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.0/0003:04D9:1702.0001/input/input0
    [    3.281099] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.5.2/input0
    [    3.346264] random: systemd urandom read with 84 bits of entropy available
    [    3.367015] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.2/1-1.5.2:1.1/0003:04D9:1702.0002/input/input1
    [    3.367363] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.5.2/input1
    [    3.406877] NET: Registered protocol family 10
    [    3.441068] usb 1-1.5.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
    [    3.575253] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB DISK 2.0     PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
    [    3.592920] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2320
    [    3.592950] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
    [    3.592966] usb 1-1.5.3: Product: Expansion
    [    3.592983] usb 1-1.5.3: Manufacturer: Seagate
    [    3.592998] usb 1-1.5.3: SerialNumber: NA41G060
    [    3.594041] usb-storage 1-1.5.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [    3.594504] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.5.3:1.0
    [    3.671001] usb 1-1.5.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
    [    3.772449] usb 1-1.5.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
    [    3.772531] usb 1-1.5.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    [    3.772547] usb 1-1.5.4: Product: USB2.0 Hub
    [    3.773859] hub 1-1.5.4:1.0: USB hub found
    [    3.774272] hub 1-1.5.4:1.0: 1 port detected
    [    3.879646] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manager.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
    [    3.879995] systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
    [    3.880027] systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
    [    3.880055] systemd[1]: Found dependency on kbd.service/start
    [    3.880082] systemd[1]: Found dependency on remote-fs.target/start
    [    3.880107] systemd[1]: Found dependency on remote-fs-pre.target/start
    [    3.880132] systemd[1]: Found dependency on connman.service/start
    [    3.880157] systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
    [    3.880184] systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job kbd.service/start
    [    3.880214] systemd[1]: Job kbd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
    [    4.167661] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 3915776 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
    [    4.167981] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
    [    4.168005] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
    [    4.168290] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
    [    4.168310] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [    4.191672]  sda: sda1
    [    4.194084] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [    4.591502] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0608 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
    [    4.593897] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
    [    4.594488] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    [    4.594511] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
    [    4.595073] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
    [    4.647967] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
    [    4.686486] fuse init (API version 7.23)
    [    4.812434] systemd-udevd[125]: starting version 215
    [    4.817856] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
    [    4.979231]  sdb: sdb1
    [    4.982866] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
    [    5.337549] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
    [    5.390083] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
    [    5.390376] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    [    5.819548] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p5): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
    [    6.488179] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
    [    7.397786] systemd-journald[106]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
    [    9.653409] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
    [    9.654248] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [    9.805755] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
    [    9.805855] NET: Registered protocol family 31
    [    9.805867] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [    9.805900] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [    9.805916] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [    9.805953] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [    9.928671] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [    9.928690] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [    9.928722] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   11.231990] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
    [   11.239235] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
    [   12.905953] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
    [   13.084481] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [   15.577166] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
    osmc@osmc:~$ lsblk
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda           8:0    1   1.9G  0 disk
    `-sda1        8:1    1   1.9G  0 part /media/28EF-85C3
    sdb           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
    `-sdb1        8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /media/Seagate Expansion Drive
    mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk
    |-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 814.3M  0 part /media/RECOVERY
    |-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0     1K  0 part
    |-mmcblk0p3 179:3    0    32M  0 part /media/SETTINGS
    |-mmcblk0p5 179:5    0    80M  0 part /boot
    `-mmcblk0p6 179:6    0   6.5G  0 part /
```

Edit2:

```
osmc@osmc:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bc2:2320 Seagate RSS LLC USB 3.0 bridge [Portable Expansion Drive]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13fe:3100 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 2/4 GB stick
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: How are you powering your rPi2? And how is the external NTFS drive powered? You might be facing these issues due to a lack of Amps.

Comment: Looks like a power issue, like Phil B. suggested.

Comment: Everything is connected to the HUB-USB (trust pyramid). When the external NTFS is not connected the both memories have the same behaviour. So I guess is not a power issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is seen when you plug in in running because the OS sees the hotplug event and mounts the drive. When you boot with the drive mounted, there is no hotplug event. So the drive does not get mounted.

If you want the drive to mount at boot, you'll need to edit your /etc/fstab-

first make a mount point-

```
mkdir /mnt/usbdrive
```

(or where ever you want it), then do -

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

and take note of the UUID. Then backup /etc/fstab and open it for editing-

```
cp /etc/fstab /home/pi/fstab.bak
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add the following line (changing the UUID and filesystem type (usually **ntfs-3g**, **vfat** or **ext4**) to your own...

```
UUID=YOUR_UUID /media/usbdrive vfat uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0
```

then save and reboot.

Note - the above line works only if you haven't removed the 'pi' user (UID 1000) as it mounts the drive as that user...

Comment: I think the issue isn't whether the drive is mounted, it's that the sticks do not even appear to be attached, therefore *cannot* be mounted, even if they are listed in `fstab`.

Comment: In that case I'd _love_ to see the dmesg of what happens during hotplug vs. the one from booting with it plugged in...

Comment: Looking through that after boot would be a good idea to see if there's any explanation.

Comment: I added the dmesg,

Comment: John, does **lsusb** list them?

Comment: alphacharlie, lsusb doesnt list them, anyway I added the result to the main message.

Comment: if lsusb is not showing them then they aren't even being seen by the PC. (i.e. @ the hardware level) I'd swap out the USB hub and/or power supply.